# как правильно сделать универсальный метод обновления записи php? laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
//1 Иногда нужно вставить такие поля в одном месте кода

            $user->status = 'closed';
            $user->profit = $profit;
            $user->profit_percent = $percent;
            $user->save();

//в 2 та же модель только обновить 
            $user->profit = $profit;
            $user->profit_percent = $percent;
            $user->save();

//в 3  
       $user->status = 'closed';
       $user->save();

Есть мысль создать сервис который вызывался ьы в в любых местах только данные передавать в него только те какие нужно обновить

class Service {
   public function update(User $user, string $status, int|float $profit, int|float $profit_percent) 
    {
        //и тут эти поля проверять как то 

    }

// или массив перебирать как правильно?
    public function update(User $user, array $parameters) 
    {
        //и тут эти поля проверять как то 
        foreach($parameters as $key => $value){
           $user->{$key} = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем какой-то отдельный сервис для этого делать? Можно же добавить сразу в модель **User** соответствующие методы и использовать их.

Например, метод **close**

```php
public function close() 
{
  $this->status = 'closed';
  $this->save();
}
```

И вызывать его в тех местах где требуется "закрыть" пользователя. Такми образом код становится понятнее. А внутри метода потом можно еще что-то добавить (если потребуется), какие-то действия по закрытию.

Аналогично можно сделать и метод для установки **profit** и **profit_percent**.

Если у вас "закрытие" аккаунта это одна отдельная операция, а установка значений другая и друг от друга они не зависят - то и не надо их реализовывать в одном методе.

Answer (score -1):

можно вынести в отдельную функцию в трейт

```
    public function upd($user, $arr){
$user->profit = $arr[profit];
$user->profit_percent = $arr[percent]; return $user;
}
```

и вызывать в нужном месте